# taking derivative of integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you take the derivative of an integral if both the bottom and the top bounds are not constants?

Taking derivative with respect to $t$: $\int^{t^3}_{t^2}cos(x^2)dx$

Comment: see here (if you meant the Leibniz rule) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: The integral is a function of $t^2,t^3:f=\int_{t^2}^{t^3}\cos(x^2)\,dx=g(t^3)-g(t^2)\quad($where $g(x)+c=\int\cos(x^2)\,dx)$.

Then $f'(t)=3t^2g'(t^3)-2tg'(t^2)=3t^2\cos(t^6)-2t\cos(t^4)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Use the fact that , if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, than we have:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int _{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(x)dx=\frac{d}{dt}\left[F(b(t))-F(a(t)) \right]=f(b(t))b'(t)-f(a(t))a'(t)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_a^c f(x) dx+\int_c^b f(x) dx$, where $c$ is a constant.